# How to Replace a string in a column on selected rows matching a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe from which I need to replace all strings in column `sense` where the string is exactly `pertain`. I can apply the following code to do the same

`pd[pd['sense'] == 'pertain']['sense'].str.replace('pertain','pertaining')`

But this does not take effect on the original dataframe. How can I make sure that the effect takes palce on the original dataset and all the `pertain` in the column will change to `pertaining`

```
 | affix    | word           |   sense       | meaning                         |
0   ical    neuroanatomical     pertaining   of or pertaining to [[neuroanatomy]]
1   ical    neuroanatomical     pertain      of or pertaining to [[neuroanatomy]]
2   ical    biotechnological    pertaining   of or pertaining to [[biotechnology]]
3   ical    biotechnological    pertain      of or pertaining to [[biotechnology]]
4   ical    educological        relating     relating to [[educology]].
```

So Ideally, after the operation my output should look like the following

```
 | affix    | word           |   sense       | meaning                         |
0   ical    neuroanatomical     pertaining   of or pertaining to [[neuroanatomy]]
1   ical    neuroanatomical     pertaining   of or pertaining to [[neuroanatomy]]
2   ical    biotechnological    pertaining   of or pertaining to [[biotechnology]]
3   ical    biotechnological    pertaining   of or pertaining to [[biotechnology]]
4   ical    educological        relating     relating to [[educology]].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `loc` with assignment, where you pass a logical vector to indicate rows where the column `sense`'s value should be replaced (assuming your data frame is named `df`):

```
df.loc[df.sense == "pertain", "sense"] = "pertaining"

df
#  affix                word         sense   meaning
#0  ical     neuroanatomical    pertaining  of or pertaining to [[neuroanatomy]]
#1  ical     neuroanatomical    pertaining  of or pertaining to [[neuroanatomy]]
#2  ical    biotechnological    pertaining  of or pertaining to [[biotechnology]]
#3  ical    biotechnological    pertaining  of or pertaining to [[biotechnology]]
#4  ical        educological    relating    relating to [[educology]].
```

---

Another method is to use `replace` only on `sense` column and then assign it back to the original data frame, which replaces the `sense` column with modified version:

```
df['sense'] = df.sense.replace("pertain", "pertaining")
```

---

With all being said, your method also works, you just need to assign it back to your original data frame as the second option above.